# Question on ROS frame convention

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I keep getting confused with this every once in a while, and I can't find a definite resource for the convention.
The frame id is supposed to be: `#Frame this data is associated with`

To represent the pose of an object in the map, I'm not sure what convention is used. i.e.. if the data should be in the frame of object (camera, robot,etc..) or in the frame of the map.  In CV, SLAM literature, the 'pose' represented by a Rotation (R), and translation (t) is usually in the frame of the camera,
i.e. `R` contains the coordinates of the bases of the `map` frame in the `Camera` frame, and `t` is the translation in the Camera frame, or `X_camera = R*X_map + t` where `X_map` is a point in the `map` frame, and `X_camera` the same point in the camera frame.

From what I understand, it seems like the the `frame_id` should be `Camera` for orientation `R` (in quaternion) and position (`t`), and `map` for orientation `inv(R)` (in quat) and position `-inv(R)*t`, but I've lost count of the number of times I've gotten confused with this. Would appreciate it if you could point me to some documentation on this convention.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410471/question-on-ros-frame-convention/) by [pointsnadpixels](https://answers.ros.org/users/33199/pointsnadpixels/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2022-12-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The documentation for the transform, and pose conventions I was looking for can be found here: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Overview/Transformations
tl;dr:

> To represent the pose of an object in the map, I'm not sure what convention is used. i.e.. if the data should be in the frame of object (camera, robot,etc..) or in the frame of the map.

For the frame_id of an object `map`, the data should be in the coordinates of the `map`, opposite to CV/SLAM convention where a `pose` of a camera is the coordinates of a `map` in the frame of the camera.

---

Originally posted by [pointsnadpixels](https://answers.ros.org/users/33199/pointsnadpixels/) with karma: 23 on 2022-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `map` frame is special. It is a frame which should be constant in time regardless of sensors, fixed to the world. Frame `T` which has a transform `map->T` should be things which are equally fixed to the world. Off the top of my head, the starting location of the robot (ie the `odom` frame) is one such thing. Another might be a navigation goal.

A detected object which sources information from the camera is not one such frame. It is clearly reliant on where the camera is, and so it should be specified in the camera frame. Any node which needs the object can get the position in any frame which has a connection to the object anyway, thanks to the power of the transform tree.

You can read more about the frame convention here https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html#map

---

Originally posted by [Per Edwardsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/79869/per-edwardsson/) with karma: 501 on 2022-12-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pointsnadpixels](https://answers.ros.org/users/33199/pointsnadpixels/) on 2022-12-15**:
Hello, I'm not sure if my question was confusing, but this is not what I meant. The question was more about the convention used for representing the data 'in a frame'.   I used 'Camera' and 'map' in my question in the context of SLAM, but it could refer to the pose of any object in any frame.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-12-15**:
Perhaps another example would be useful in the question edit, because I understood your question nearly the same way (frame and data associated with it)

**Comment by [Per Edwardsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/79869/per-edwardsson/) on 2022-12-16**:
Hmm. Do you understand what a frame is in this context? I think of them as origins for a coordinate system. The camera frame, then, is a coordinate system based on the camera. A transform is a matrix that moves frame A to frame B via matrix multiplication. The location of the object in that frame is well defined as a Pose (http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseStamped.html), ie a 3D point and a 4D quaternion, and always in relation to the frame. You typically don't need to consider other representation unless you need anything specific, since `tf2_ros` takes care of any transforming between them.

**Comment by [pointsnadpixels](https://answers.ros.org/users/33199/pointsnadpixels/) on 2022-12-16**:
"The location of the object in that frame is well defined as a Pose (http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/geo...), ie a 3D point and a 4D quaternion, and always in relation to the frame."
This 'relation' is defined depending on convention, which is what my question is. In a pose message, when frame_id is 'map', is the pose then the coordinates of the 'object' in the 'map' or vice versa (coordinates of the bases of 'map' in the frame of the object). In SLAM, 3D reconstruction,etc. literature a pose wrt a map is the latter.

EDIT: To clarify, the 'vice versa' is the coordinates of the map/world/whatever frame in the frame of the 'camera/object/..'

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-12-17**:
@pointsnadpixels

```
In SLAM, 3D reconstruction,etc. literature a pose wrt a map is the latter.
```

This statement shows a deep misunderstanding of the calculation being done. A Pose can be represented by a 4x4 matrix, and the object T used to transform PoseA from frameA to frameB can also be represented by a 4x4 matrix. This transform matrix is NOT a Pose. And if we take the inverse of the transform matrix, it's still not a Pose.

**Comment by [pointsnadpixels](https://answers.ros.org/users/33199/pointsnadpixels/) on 2022-12-17**:
How so? A pose can very much be seen as a transform. While computing the Projection matrix for a camera, the extrinsics parameters (R,t) are quite literally the pose of the camera wrt a world , where R in this case is the coordinates of the bases of the world frame in the camera frame, and 't' the position of the origin of the world frame in the camera coordinate system.
i.e.  `X_c = R*X_w + t` where `X_w` is a point in the world frame, and `X_c` is the same point in the camera frame . There is plenty of literature which you can very easily look up.

**Comment by [pointsnadpixels](https://answers.ros.org/users/33199/pointsnadpixels/) on 2022-12-19**:
Hello @Mike Scheutzow can you please expand on why you think this interpretation is a misunderstanding?

**Comment by [Per Edwardsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/79869/per-edwardsson/) on 2022-12-20**:
@pointsnadpixels, wrt your earlier comment, if a message of type PoseStamped has a header with frame_id of 'map', then the pose described in that message is given in terms of the 'map' frame. The nomenclature is maybe a little unfortunate here: in ROS, a *frame* is essentially a coordinate system, defined in the world (through a 3D point and a 4D quaternion). A *transform* takes you from one frame to another, such that B = XA, where A and B are frames, and X is a transform. Poses, here, are a type of message, linked above. It is very possible to transfer the information contained in a frame (3d point + quat) into another medium. Typically, the camera 3x4 projection matrix is not used. They both contain the same information, but saying that transform is a pose is going to be confusing in this context.

**Comment by [pointsnadpixels](https://answers.ros.org/users/33199/pointsnadpixels/) on 2022-12-20**:
@Per Edwardsson thanks for the comment. .

> but saying that transform is a pose is going to be confusing in this context.

The terminology is confusing as hell, but I finally found the right documentation I was looking for (in a rather obvious place): http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Overview/Transformations and it looks like they use 'pose' and 'transform'  as dual.

From the document:

> The relationship between two frames is represented by a 6 DOF relative pose, a translation followed by a rotation. If W and A are two frames, the pose of A in W is given by the translation from W's origin to A's origin, and the rotation of A's coordinate axes in W.

This is actually pretty much exactly what I wanted to know in terms of convention.

@Mike Scheutzow the linked docs explains the duality, in interpretation, between a 'pose' and 'transform'.